# Running FFMPEG and FFserver from Glassfish Java Servlet

Tags: java, linux, servlets, ffmpeg, glassfish

I'm planning to design a web interface to control my FFserver remotely. The question is, is it possible to start/stop the FFserver running on my Linux server using a Servlet running on the same machine?

I'm using Glassfish server and Java EE 7 for my web application. Currently I managed to get my web app to obtain http streams (which are started manually in terminal with predefined config file) and play them on the web. However, now I want to find a way to stop the streams and start the streams on demand.

Is it possible for me to run a Bash script via the servlet? Or are there any better solutions which allows Servlets to run linux commands in the servlet?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Hi John, noted. Thank you for your comment.